# How do I return large number of columns from mysql database using AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql

A brief background: I have a serverless mysql database connected to AWS RDS which consists of 70 columns and 7000+ rows. Many of the columns defined in this RDS have datatype as `VARCHAR(2000), BIGINT`.

I'm trying to return all the details in this database using an AWS Lambda api, following is the code snippet of the handler function that I'm using to achieve the same:

```
def handler(event, context):
    try:

        #Storing data to be returned
        dataReturn=[]



        #Insert Data into Database
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("SELECT <names of all 70 columns> FROM <table_name>" ) 
            row_headers=[x[0] for x in cur.description] #this will extract row headers
            rv = cur.fetchall()
            json_data=[]
            for result in rv:
                json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
            #print(json.dumps(json_data))
            conn.commit()



        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
            },
            'body': json.dumps(json_data, cls=DecimalEncoder)
        }
    except Exception: 
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        return {
            'statusCode': 502,
            'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
            },
            'body': json.dumps("Server Error Occured", cls=DecimalEncoder)
        }
```

However, when I run this it gives me a '502 server error' with the following logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/getInstrumentsDetails.py", line 55, in handler
    print(json.dumps(json_data))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

As a sidenote, I am able to return 24 columns from this table using:
 `SELECT <name_of_25_columns> FROM <table_name>`, but it fails if I try to display more than 24 columns.

Is this an issue related to the amount of memory that AWS Lambda can read/return from the RDS?
Please suggest a suitable fix to this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem isn't the number of columns, but is instead that after 24 columns, your 25th column is a decimal type - at least, that is what the error message is actually reporting.

Your return function specifies an encoder, but your print statement does not - it is commented out in your code above, but the error message you are showing does not have the encoder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/getInstrumentsDetails.py", line 55, in handler
    print(json.dumps(json_data))
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but my 9th column is also decimal, which it is able to display. Also, it shows the same error even if I uncomment the print statement

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the definition for your **DecimalEncoder** above but you should be able to use something as simple as:

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, bytes):
            if len(obj) == 1:
                return ord(obj)
            else:
                return obj.decode()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Note that if you want to print the result of **json.dumps** you need to pass the custom encoder there as well: `print(json.dumps(json_data), cls=DecimalEncoder)`.

Regarding the memory question: Lambda can use **128** MB to **3008** MB, in 64 MB increments; having **7000+** rows with many `varchar` columns can result in a considerable amount of memory being used; first make sure your code is correct by using a `LIMIT` clause in your query and then try to run it for the whole data.

Note: you have a `dataReturn` variable you don't use and you have a `conn.commit()` statement that should not be necessary when reading (**SELECT**ing) data.

**Update**: based on the new data it seems your issue is with `byte` data not `Decimal`: `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

For example, column `Is_Record_Day_Wrkng` is a byte with the value `\x00`; if these byte values should actually be numbers you can use `ord` to encode them in JSON but if not you should use something like `bytes.decode` - see updated encode above.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to increase the memory of the lambda and have also tried to display 1 row using LIMIT 1, but it still gives the same error

Comment: Also, I have defined the exact same decimal encoder which is being used in my return body

Comment: Try printing `json_data` without `json.dumps` just so we can see which types it contains; the first row should suffice.

Comment: It is displaying all the 70 key value pairs with the following: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/<filename>.py", line 106, in handler
    'body': json.dumps(json_data, cls=DecimalEncoder)```

Comment: There's no indication of what exception is being thrown there; use something like *pastebin* to paste the complete output.

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions have a cap on the amount of data they will transfer by default but you can change it in API gateway in your aws console.